# OKHttp get http transferStart time and transferDone tiem under Android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, okhttp

I'm trying port a system from Linux to Android, something like [http trace](https://blog.golang.org/http-tracing), Likely [httpstat outputs](https://github.com/davecheney/httpstat)

```
  DNS Lookup   TCP Connection   TLS Handshake   Server Processing   Content Transfer
[    302ms  |         416ms  |       1353ms  |            403ms  |             0ms  ]
            |                |               |                   |                  |
   namelookup:302ms          |               |                   |                  |
                       connect:719ms         |                   |                  |
                                   pretransfer:2079ms            |                  |
                                                     starttransfer:2483ms           |
                                                                                total:2483ms
```

I could make a self tls stack replace initial one so that I could get TLS Handshake start and over time, And I need three data like

"**first byte time**": [FirstResponseByte](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptrace/#ClientTrace)

"**download time**": (for the content was downloaded Finish)

"**redirect time**": (if have redirect)

And for now I'm not really familiar with OKHttp, And I searched It seems did not expose these data.

So Is there any way I could get there params? Or even with Other implementations like HttpUrlConnection?

Comment: Did you publish an app with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [EventListener](https://square.github.io/okhttp/events/).